# BC30420 'Sub Main' was not found error in a Windows Form app

Tags: vb.net

I've created a Windows Form application.  It is my understanding that you do not have to have a Sub Main() in a Windows Form app.  However I'm getting this error when I build my project:

```
BC30420 'Sub Main' was not found in 'LoanCalculator.Module1'.
```

First of all I don't know why it's saying 'LoanCalculator.Module1'.  Both my form and my class are named LoanCalculator.vb.  When I started the project I started writing the code in the original module.  Then I added a module, named it 'LoanCalculator' and moved what code I had written to that module and finished it there.  I deleted the original module.  Now it builds fine with the exception of this one error.  Here's my code:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class LoanCalculator

    Private Sub Calculate()
        Dim str As String
        Dim intLoanAmt As Integer
        Dim intDown As Integer
        Dim intFees As Integer
        Dim intBalance As Integer
        Dim dblIntsRate As Single
        Dim intLoanTerm As Integer
        Dim sngInterestPaid As Single
        Dim intTermMonths As Integer
        Dim dblMonthlyPmt As Integer
        Dim intTotalPaid As Integer
        Dim dblYon As Double
        Dim dblXon As Double
        Dim dblZon As Double

        If Not CheckInput() Then
            Return
        End If

        intLoanAmt = Convert.ToInt32(txtLoan.Text)
        intFees = Convert.ToInt32(txtFees.Text)
        intDown = Convert.ToInt32(txtDown.Text)
        intBalance = Convert.ToInt32(intLoanAmt - intDown + intFees)
        intLoanTerm = Convert.ToInt32(txtTerm.Text)
        dblIntsRate = Convert.ToDouble(txtTerm.Text)
        intTermMonths = intLoanTerm * 12
        dblYon = dblIntsRate / 1200
        dblXon = dblYon + 1
        dblZon = Math.Pow(dblXon, intTermMonths) - 1
        dblMonthlyPmt = (dblYon + (dblYon / dblZon)) * intBalance
        intTotalPaid = dblMonthlyPmt * intTermMonths
        sngInterestPaid = intTotalPaid - intBalance
        str = "Loan balance =" & Space(11) & intBalance.ToString & vbCrLf
        str = str & "Loan Term =" & Space(16) & intLoanTerm.ToString & " years" & vbCrLf
        str = str & "Interest paid =" & Space(17) & intTotalPaid.ToString & vbCrLf
        str = str & "Monthly payment =" & Space(5) & dblMonthlyPmt.ToString
        lblResults.Text = str

    End Sub

    Private Function CheckInput() As Boolean
        Dim strErr As String = ""

        If txtLoan.Text.Length = 0 Then
            strErr = "Enter loan amount" & vbCrLf
        End If

        If txtDown.Text.Length = 0 Then
            strErr = strErr & "Enter down payment" & vbCrLf
        End If

        If txtInterest.Text.Length = 0 Then
            strErr = strErr & "Enter interest rate" & vbCrLf
        End If

        If txtFees.Text.Length = 0 Then
            strErr = strErr & "Enter fees" & vbCrLf
        End If

        If txtTerm.Text.Length = 0 Then
            strErr = strErr & "Enter loan term" & vbCrLf
        End If

        If strErr.Length > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show(strErr)
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just check the startup form isn't referencing to an old method. Can find that in your project properties.

Comment: Sub Main is still needed unless you have specify a startup form

Comment: That was it Bugs.  Thanks.