# BC30420 'Sub Main' was not found in 'quicktest4'. after finding that this error could be caused by a install fail I repaired visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

so I'm new to visual studio and I wanted to use the visual basic functionality of the program but when I try to compile and run my VB I get the BC30420 'Sub Main' was not found in 'quicktest4' error code. I looked around on the internet to see what could cause this and found that it could be and error with the install itself, knowing that I proceeded to use the repair function in the installer and got the same error. I've also tried deleting the entire program and reinstalling and got no change as well. I also read a post on this website saying that it could be something about the properties so I checked there and did not see anything out of place. Link: [BC30420 'Sub Main' was not found error in a Windows Form app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048271/bc30420-sub-main-was-not-found-error-in-a-windows-form-app)

Any help would be appreciated greatly, I really would like to actually start building stuff. this has been a two day ordeal so far.

If it involves adding code, please tell me where because this system is pretty foreign to me.

EDIT: Adding a screenshot of the quicktest code itself
[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjsyW.png)

Comment: Please give us more detail about your code. It's far more likely that you don't have a Main method than that this is an environmental issue. If you can provide a [mcve] that would be the best option.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to my question, lmk if this is not the right area for the code.

Comment: Please don't add code or project files as screenshots - it's text, so include it *as text* in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your properties. Sometimes it sets the initial form to main instead of form 1.